# Add Items to ListBox and Style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controls, listbox

I have a simple class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool AppleStyle { get; set; }

    public Foo(string text, bool applyStyle)
    {
        Text = text;
        ApplyStyle = applyStyle;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

Which is then used to add items to a `ListBox`:

```
var one = new Foo("Some Text", false);
var two = new Foo("More Text", true);
MyListBox.Items.Add(one);
MyListBox.Items.Add(two);
```

I then loop through the items in the `ListBox` to figure out how to style them. This is where I get stuck. I tried inheriting from `ListBoxItem` for the class, but no items get added if I do that.

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyListBox.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if(((Foo)MyListBox.Items[i]).ApplyStyle)
    {
        ((ListBoxItem)MyListBox.Items[i]).Style = Resources["MyStyle"] as Style;        
    }
}
```

**Update:**
In `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Bisque"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

**Update 3:**
Making some progress, just need to know how to refresh the styles (after clicking on a button). Plus if Resource is not in MainWindow.xaml, would it then look in App.xaml before returning null?

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyClass" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Bisque"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
        </Style>
        <myapp:MyListItemStyleSelector x:Key="MyListItemStyleSelector" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
    ...
        <ListBox .... ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource: MyListItemStyleSelector}" />
    ...
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MyListItemStyleSelector.cs

```
public class MyListItemStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
    public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        ItemsControl ic = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(container);
        int index = ic.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(container);
        Style applyStyle = null;
        var data = item as Foo;
        if (data != null && data.ApplyStyle)
        {
            applyStyle = ic.TryFindResource("MyStyle") as Style;
        }
        return applyStyle;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some sort of mixup here, i try to explain as good as i can.

First of all You usually never need to change the Style in code, like your last code block.
One thing that is difficult to understand in the beginning is the use of a `ItemContainerStyle` and `DataTemplate`.

I would suggest that you do the following.

Instead of changing the style off your ListBoxItem see if it is sufficient to use a DataTemplate. The DataTemplate defines how the Content of your ListBoxItem is shown.

```
<DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Foo}">
 <!-- your visuals and controls here -->
</DataTemplate>
```

Now if you want to use different datatemplates you could use different classes and create different DataTemplates for them, or you use a [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx)

```
 public class FooTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;
            var mdl = item as Foo;
            if( mdl.AppleStyle )
                return element.FindResource("appleTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            return element.FindResource("normalTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
    }
```

Create that templateselector in xaml and reference it in your listbox

```
<myNs:FooTemplateSelector x:Key="fooTemplateSelector"/>

<Listbox DataTemplateSelector="{StaticResource fooTemplateSelector}"/>
```

now you need to create 2 `DataTemplate`s *appleTemplate* *normalTemplate* and you can easyl distinguish which data template to use vial the selector. Which is done automatically in the ListBox for you.

If you really want to change the Style of the ItemContainer you can use [ItemContainerStyleSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyleselector.aspx) which works similar to the DataTemplateSelector. But i would not suggest it. You should supply the content and leave the ListBoxItem as it is, only if you want to modify the design(in this case, the selection color etc.), otherwise it might confuse the user or break functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you add data-objects directly to the `ListBox` the container-items will be generated automatically, you cannot get them this way.

Use the [`ItemContainerGenerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainergenerator.aspx):

```
((ListBoxItem)MyListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i)).Style = Resources["MyStyle"] as Style;
```

Comment: I get `NullReferenceException` when doing that, which suggests it is not loading the style (maybe I have it defined in the wrong place)

Comment: Some time should have passed between adding the items and doing this, further you will run into problems if your ListBox will virtualize the items since then there will at no point be a container for items which are not scrolled into view. It would be better to do this via the `ItemContainerStyleSelector` of the ListBox.

Comment: when Resources property is used as dictionary, the key should be present exactly in that ResourceDictionary. If you need logical tree lookup it is better to use TryGetResource method. Still much better way of condifional styles is by using triggers or template selectors.

Comment: `NullReferenceException` was cause by `((ListBoxItem)MyListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i))`, the style was found

Comment: @SamWM: You need to add `(at)Username` otherwise it will be addressed at the post owner (me) and not the person you are actually trying to talk to (who will not be notified)..

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this in the XAML?

```
<ListBox Name="MyListBox">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ApplyStyle}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Bisque" />
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

But your overall problem is that `ListBox.Items` returns a collection of data objects, not XAML Controls. To get the XAML control that contains the Data Object you have to do as H.B. suggested and use `MyListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dataObject)` to get the XAML Container for the data object. Just be sure you wait until after the ItemContainerGenerator has finished rendering items to get the container (I believe it has a `Status` property or `StatusChanged` event you can use... it's been a while and I can't remember the exact syntax)

Comment: How can you add a XAML control containing the data object, since I still need to check the various properties of each item in the list?

Comment: Setting the `Style` property in a `Setter` is not allowed for more or less obvious reasons...

Comment: lol Whoops, I didn't read what I wrote that carefully. I have set styles within a style, but it has always been properties like `ItemContainerStyle`, not the `Style` property. Sorry.

Comment: Is your style that complex? Could you actually define it within the `ListBoxItem` style instead of a `Window.Resources` style? (See edited answer)

Comment: It's just to change the background colour of a `ListBoxItem`. You pick an item (or more than one) in the `ListBox` control, click a button and the `ApplyStyle` is set on the object (to true or false) and the background colour in the list box should change. Another button then does something with those 'marked' items (this bit works, but the styling doesn't)